# Template fields, bound fields? is any performance issue?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, when we use grid view control, what is the difference between or performance issue when we use Item template instead of bound fields. Any draw back.

Answer (score 0):

The **BoundField** displays the value of specified DataSource field as text 
and 
**TemplateField** allows for a mix of HTML markup, Web controls, and data-binding syntax.

So ultimately both the things render html output at the end(browser side) and creating text or any control at client side will not become issue of performance.

You can not render any event of specific control in bound field it just display data of datasource as a plain text while you can bind data with many different html controls in case of templatefield.

Finally i don't think either bound field or template field lead you to performance issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply dilip, i observe when i debug the gridview if it is itemtemplate the debugger come to every column in item template. but same thing not for boundfield.

Comment: When you use bound field it takes the data as a text only and in text no event is possible , while in case of template it contains some event like for checkbox check_change event is there likewisre , I think for that reason debugger will go there.